# Return statement with expression after a new line is broken

Tags: javascript

Here's a minimal working example that I have:

```
function foo () {
    return
        1;
}

function bar () {
    return 1;
}
console.log(foo()); //Undefined
console.log(bar()); //1
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mve3crm5/

I expect both `foo()` and `bar()` to return `1`.

However, `foo()` returns `undefined`, `bar()` returns `1`.

**Assuming this is expected behaviour, Why?**

I don't use JavaScript often so this confuses the heck out of me. A friend recommended I use "strict mode" but I tried it and the same behaviour happens.

I tested this on Chrome and node v7.4.0, also with the node --use_strict flag.

I had my expression on a new line because the particular expression I was returning wasn't complicated but quite long. I split the expression into multiple lines and was surprised to get an `undefined` value.

I debugged everything in the system and concluded there was nothing wrong except the `return` statement but refused to believe it. Then, I tried to put together a minimal example and saw that it is, indeed, the case.

I am forced to believe that this is how JavaScript works, despite still being skeptical. I am partially convinced I probably have a typo somewhere, somehow.

Comment: It’s called “automatic semicolon insertion” and is one of JavaScript’s stupidest features. Linters can catch this for you, though.

Comment: I'm not an expert either, but JavaScript automatically adds semi colons to the end of the line.  So it probably becomes return; 1;   Since this behavior is slightly unpredictable people try to code in a way that prevents JavaScript from guessing

Comment: `JavaScript automatically adds semi colons to the end of the line` under some circumstances only

Comment: Ryan is correct, and now we're stuck with it because changing it would mean all those *we don't need semicolons anymore* proponents out there would suddenly have broken code.

Comment: Agh, that's horrible. I'm looking at this now: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons and it has an example with the exact issue I encountered today =/

Comment: TIL, thanks, guys!